# Identify controls in second form using Coded ui test in dot net using WPF project

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to hand coded UI test. I have a main form and there is a lOGIN button.when i click a button, it goes to userdetails page.There I have a view Button. I want to identify the view button in second form which is opened when i click a Login button. The view button is not recognized. How to pass the second form(userdetails) window to WpfButton control.

Any Help would be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first identify the form and then pass it as parent to the button control.
some thing like this:

```
WinWindow userdetailsFrom = new WinWindow();
        userdetailsFrom.SearchProperties.Add(the Search properties you want);

WinButton viewBtn = new WinButton(userdetailsFrom);
        viewBtn.SearchProperties(the SearchConfiguration properties you identify);
```